# Caching Invalidation Strategy with mongodb & redis

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis

I have built a redis cache layer for my application with are using mongodb.
I'm concerned about caching invalidation because the update command can submit to the mongodb in various way such as update by id, code, name... etc

How can we find the related cached resource to update accordingly ?

I already have tried to use the 'Stream Change' feature of mongodb to evict the cache but I got the performance degradation due to the mongodb open the new connection for each change stream (prefer to this [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32946))

For example:

1. I cache the order {id:1, code:2, user:3} with id = 1 in redis
2. When application update all orders with user=3, how can we know to update the corresponding order in redis

Answer (score 1):

1/ Either make it a part of your CRUD operations being done through your code & mongodb driver, redis operations are fast, and would not hamper performance by big margin. So you can invalidate or modify your redis structures whenever you do a mongodb operation in your code.

2/ In case you want to keep the system independent, I would recommend listening to collection & document changes through **debezium**, which would publish the change events into a Kafka Topic. A consumer of the kafka topic can read the events and modify the cache accordingly.
https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/

Comment: Thanks @DhruvPathak, will try with debezium